# Access combo box to return value from another table

Tags: sql

I have a table called **`initial_eval`** that has a field called **`Partno`**.

1. What I would like to do is match the **`Partno`** value in a field
   also called 'Partno' from a table called 'update'.
2. What I would then like to do is return the value in the
   'consumption' field of 'update' where the 'Partno' values match.

I'm ok with SQL and join stuff, but I can't crack this one

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT U.CONSUMPTION FROM UPDATE U 
WHERE U.PARTNO IN (SELECT PARTNO FROM INITIAL_EVAL)
```

This assumes there is no condition while fetching from `INITIAL_EVAL`

```
SELECT U.CONSUMPTION FROM UPDATE U 
WHERE U.PARTNO = (SELECT PARTNO FROM INITIAL_EVAL WHERE **some condition**)
```

In this case you need to frame the inner query in a such a way that it returns exactly one row which will automatically map to your `CONSUMPTION` table row.

Comment: Hi, this almost works, but I would like the lookup to be automatic. I would like the consumption value to be returned from the row where the part numbers match. Please advise

Comment: NP. Can you please mark this as the correct answer?